# What is the function of distribution of $X$? What is the density function of $X$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Assume that a point is randomly selected within the interior of the
circle of radius $R$ centered on the origin of the plane. Let $X$ be the square
of the distance of the selected point to the origin.

What is the function
of distribution of $X$?

What is the density function of $X$?

The euclidian distance from the origin is: $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

so $X = x^2 + y^2$

My problem is that I don´t know how to establish a probability values for that. I think that having $x$ and $y$ variables confuses me.

Comment: Consider how the length of a curve that defines all points with the same distance from the origin (in other words, a circle) grows linearly as you increase that distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be nonnegative

\begin{align}
P(X \le r^2) = \frac{\pi r^2}{\pi R^2} =\frac{r^2}{R^2}
\end{align}

That is we can write

$$P(X \le x) = \frac{x}{R^2}$$

I will let you develop the density from here.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that having $x$ and $y$ variables confuses me.

Ignore them.   They are irrelevant other than establishing that the distance measure is Euclidian.

This allows you to deduce the probability density function for $\surd X$, using Euclidean geometry.

[ All points of distance $r$ from the centre of the circle will lie on the circumference of a circle with radius $r$, ... ]